# Is there a difference in using Spring Kafka MessageListenerContainer pause and pausePartition?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

For slow processing consumer, we pause the container using
`MessageListenerContainer::pause`
and resume container once the message processing is completed.

On a recent Spring kafka version upgrade, we found another method called

`MessageListenerContainer::pausePartition`

Can we assume, pausePartition is a better approach as it gives ability to pause specific partition while consuming message versus the container ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that exactly means that you pause a specific partition while container can still consume from others.